# how to convert byte array or binary data into audio file

Tags: iphone

I need help in my iphone application, I want to  convert byte array or binary data into audio file.Please help me out and tell me any way so i con do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is supposed to contain audio data in PCM format, than you can simply add WAVE header at the beginning to get ready to play audio file. Format of header is described [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Comment: In my array i have values of sampled waveform like 0.01,0.05..... and - 0.02 like that. How i will get PCM format in my array can u please exaplain ?

Comment: You array is in pcm form with BitsPerSample = 32, so you just have to that header in front of data.